# If [sentence] is [adjective]

Tags: grammaticality

I re-wrote sentences to start Unclear below. Correct if I move "unclear" to end?

[From *poverty-stricken* to *government-funded*:
on the the diachrony of English noun-participle compounding](http://www.elenasmirnova.de/fileadmin/_es/workshop_downloads/Abstract_Hilpert.pdf).
Martin Hilpert, Université de Neuchâtel

> There is some initial evidence to suggest that noun-participle compounding are, in
>   synchronic usage, independent from the English passive. First, not all passive sentences
>   have counterparts in idiomatic noun-participle compounds, consider for instance
>   unattested formations such as ?car-transported (The cargo was transported by car) or ?
>   guest-preferred (The guided tours were preferred by the guests). Second, forms such as
>   Atlanta-based or work-related do instantiate noun-participle compounding, but these
>   formations correspond to predicative constructions (The company is based in Atlanta;
>   The problem is related to work) similar to the German Zustandspassiv, rather than to
>   canonical passive sentences. **<s>What is</s> [U]nclear is if these more problematic examples
>   represent a recent development or whether they are in fact central members of the
>   constructional category.**

If these more problematic examples
represent a recent development or whether they are in fact central members of the
constructional category, is unclear.

[*First Language Phonetic Drift During Second Language Acquisition*](http://www.linguistics.berkeley.edu/PhonLab/documents/2010/Chang_diss.pdf). Charles Bond Chang - ‎2010. p. 171.

> Thus, just as there seems to be a “sweet spot” of distance from L1
>   for inducing assimilatory phonetic drift, so too might there be a “sweet spot” of
>   distance from L1 for inducing dissimilatory phonetic drift: an L2 sound has to be
>   distant enough from L1 sounds to be considered a “new” sound, yet not so distant
>   that there is no L1 sound within its vicinity. **<s>What remains</s> [U]nclear is if there is
>   indeed a degree of distance from L1 that qualifies as too far to cause dissimilation.**
>   Moreover, the SLM’s formulation of the basis for cross-language dissimilation in terms
>   of segmental categories implies that dissimilation can only occur at the segmental
>   level, but whether this holds true remains to be seen.

If there is
indeed a degree of distance from L1 that qualifies as too far to cause dissimilation, remains unclear.

Comment: For my money it would be best to leave *What remains unclear* at the front of each of these sentences. They are very long. Not too bad at all, but long. To suddenly reverse the sense of them at the end would make them less clear. *Remains unclear* could legitimately be put to the end but why(?!)

Answer (score 1):

FIRST PARAGRAPH:

What is unclear is whether these more problematic examples represent a recent development or are in fact central members of the constructional category.

OR

Whether these more problematic examples represent a recent development or are in fact central members of the constructional category is unclear.

OR

It is unclear whether these more problematic examples represent a recent development or are in fact central members of the constructional category.

SECOND PARAGRAPH:

What remains unclear is whether there is indeed a degree of distance from L1 that qualifies as too far to cause dissimilation.

OR

**Whether or not** there is indeed a degree of distance from L1 that qualifies as too far to cause dissimilation remains unclear.

If you really wanted to start with 'If', you *could* say:

If there is indeed a degree of distance from L1 that qualifies as too far to cause dissimilation, **that fact** remains unclear.

But it's not as idiomatic.

We don't use 'Unclear' at the start of a sentence.